# Setting default charset/collation for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set

I have a MySQL DB that used to be latin1, and I changed all the columns in all the tables to be utf8. However, I evidently didn't do all I had to do, because I just found that I have a crazy mixture of latin and utf8. Basically, any new tables and columns are different.

Is there a way to set the default charset and collation for the database, so that when I add new tables to *this* database they are utf8?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'd like to encourage you to visit [DBA.SE] for any database configuration and tuning issues you might face.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can set the default character set and collation on various levels.

First, in your question, on the [database level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-database.html):

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo 
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8' DEFAULT COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
```

or

```
ALTER DATABASE foo
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8' DEFAULT COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
```

All new tables in that database should be created with the new character set and database if it's not specified in the table creation command (**if it is specified in table command, the specification will override the database default**).

You can set the default at a server level (so that all tables are created with the default for all databases unless explicitly stated otherwise) by providing the [`--character-set-server`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-server) and [`--collation-server`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_collation-server) options in your my.cnf and restarting the server.

And finally, verify the client connection settings. [This doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html) explains how the client connection can fine-tune (and override) the default settings.

Comment: You should also check that the clients default char-set is correct, as the db server can have a different default to the clients!

Comment: @DTest : Concise and direct answer. +1 !!!

Comment: Use `utf8_unicode_ci`. See [stackoverflow entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci) why.